# Formik validation onBlur and even onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, error-handling, formik

I am new to Formik. I need the validate the form onBlur and even onSubmit.

Here both are getting conflict. If I check the field touched condition works only for onBlur and If I remove the touched condition all the field error messages are showing at the same time even though I touched only one field.

I do not know how to resolve this issue. Please help me with this.